# How to convert Flutter color to string and back to a color

Tags: dart, flutter

I am converting a Color to a String. I am then converting the Color to a String. Unfortunately when I want to convert it back into a Color the operation fails:

```
   Color pickerColor = new Color(0xff443a49);
    String testingColorString = pickerColor.toString();

   Color newColor;

   newColor = testingColorString as Color;
```

type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Color' in type cast where
  String is from dart:core
  Color is from dart:ui

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In Dart the `as` operator doesn't allow you to change the actual structure of an Object, it just allows you to provide a hint that an object *might* have a more specific type.  For example, if you had a dog and an animal class you could use as to specify that your animal is actually a dog (as long as the object *is* actually a dog).

```
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}

Animal animal = new Dog();
Dog bob = animal as Dog; // works, since animal is actually a dog
Animal animal2 = new Animal();
Dog bob2 = animal2 as Dog; // fails, since animal2 is actually an Animal
```

Now, in the example you've provided `toString` actually just creates a String representation of the current `Color` value.  And since this object is a String, you can't change it back to a `Color` with an `as`.  Instead, you can parse the String into a value and construct a new `Color` object.

```
Color color = new Color(0x12345678);
String colorString = color.toString(); // Color(0x12345678)
String valueString = colorString.split('(0x')[1].split(')')[0]; // kind of hacky..
int value = int.parse(valueString, radix: 16);
Color otherColor = new Color(value);
```

Answer (score 40):

You actually can't do that. Color doesn't have a constructor that accepts a String as a representation of a color.

For that, you could use the Color property [value](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Color/value.html). It is a 32 bit **int** value that represents your color. You can save it and then use to create your new Color object.

The code could look like this

```
Color pickerColor = new Color(0xff443a49);
int testingColorValue = pickerColor.value;
String testingColorString = pickerColor.toString();

Color newColor = new Color(testingColorValue);
```

or like this

```
Color pickerColor = new Color(0xff443a49);
String testingColorString = pickerColor.toString();

Color newColor = new Color(pickerColor.value);
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer even though the solution does not use String as a transitional type

Comment: It also give me a way to save a Material.color using  json_serializable. So thanks for that!

Answer (score 37):

Leveraging the power of Dart extensions we can augment **String** with a function that returns a **Color**:

```
extension ColorExtension on String {
  toColor() {
    var hexColor = this.replaceAll("#", "");
    if (hexColor.length == 6) {
      hexColor = "FF" + hexColor;
    }
    if (hexColor.length == 8) {
      return Color(int.parse("0x$hexColor"));
    }
  }
}
```

Set a string color code value in the color property.

```
 child: Text("Text Color",
             style: TextStyle(
             color: '#55B9F4'.toColor(),
              ),
             )
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the following code to get hex value of the color.

```
Color color = Colors.red;
var hexCode = '#${color.value.toRadixString(16).substring(2, 8)}';
```

Answer (score 4):

Another easy way to save color in firebase and retrieve is to first to save the value of the color as String and store this value in firebase like this.

```
Color black = Colors.black; // example black color

String _storeColorValue = black.value.toString() ;
```

This is will give 4278190080 as the black color value. you store this value as String to firebase.
You can retrieve color value and change it back to color like this :

```
int value = int.parse(_storeColorValue);

Color color = Color(value).withOpacity(1);
```

This is will give us back the color with help of the color value and withOpacity(1) which returns a new color that matches the value we passed in.

Answer (score 1):

If using JsonSerialize, you can use this:

```
class ColorConverter implements JsonConverter<Color, int> {
  const ColorConverter();
  @override Color fromJson(int json) => Color(json);
  @override int toJson(Color object) => object.value;
}
```

Then annote your color field ike this:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class MyClass {
  @ColorConverter Color myColor;
}
```

Very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Add this two functions

```
int convertToInt(Color color) {
return color.value;
}



Color convertToColor(int intColor) {
return Color(intColor);
}
```

then you can just

```
int intcolor = ColorUtils().convertToInt(Colors.amber); //convert the color to int
print(intcolor.toString()); //se it
Color mycolor = ColorUtils().convertToColor(intcolor); //retrieve the color
```

Now if you really want to store it as String, just do:

```
intcolor.toString();
```

and when retrieve it from firestore

```
Color mycolor = ColorUtils().convertToColor(int.Parse(retrievedStrColor));
```

Answer (score -1):

use this site to convert hex color to rgb color and set folow code

https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hexadecimal.asp

backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(212, 23,79, 0.99),