# How to convert color to string in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
Color pickerColor = new Color(0xff38ada9);
String colorString = pickerColor.toString();
Color newColor = Color(pickerColor.value);
```

But I got this error

> Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

```
String colorString = this.pickerColor.toString();
Color newColor = Color(this.pickerColor.value);
```

I tried this and I got this error

> Invalid reference to 'this' expression

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Flutter color to string and back to a color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835146/how-to-convert-flutter-color-to-string-and-back-to-a-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
Color pickerColor = new Color(0xff38ada9);
```

with

```
static Color pickerColor = new Color(0xff38ada9);
```

And you won't have any error in

```
String colorString = pickerColor.toString();
Color newColor = Color(pickerColor.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

Never initialize a class variable during it's declaration unless it is `static`.
But making the variable static will create a common copy for all the objects/Widgets you create with it. Also, it will be easily accessible outside the class.

Note : This error has no relation with your question.

In order to convert Color to String you'll just need to use `toString()` getter function on the color in which you want to convert to String.

Sample Code:

```
Color(0xffffffff).toString() // This is what you were looking for.
```

Comment: Nothing leave it

Comment: You can delete your comments if you wish to.