# Uploading Data into Cloud Firestore's Database

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm uploading some user data into firebase's database, but one of the variables is the background color, which is of type Color.

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'Color'
```

How can I upload that? Until now I've only used the **type string** in the collection.

This is what I'm using:

```
final Color _backgroundColor;
...
onPressed: () {
  _firestore.collection('users').add({
    'backgroundColor': _backgroundColor,
  })
}
```

What **type** (for the variable Color) should I choose in the collection? Or should I change something in the code? The code does work though, because for the variables of **type string** it didn't throw an exception.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: firebase doesnt know what is `Color`, so you have to convert it to text or some other value which you can decode later when you fetch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore can only store data of specific types as [listed here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). As you can see from that documentation, it cannot store Flutter's `Color` type.

So you'll need to define your own mapping from `Color` to and from a type that Firestore supports. Most common is to store such data as a string or a 3-bit number. See [How to convert Flutter color to string and back to a color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835146/how-to-convert-flutter-color-to-string-and-back-to-a-color), specifically the answer about [string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835615) and [number conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835427).

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is probably json encoding. Here is a link with a good example.

https://codetober.com/json-encode-decode-with-flutter/

After you have the json you can just store it as text in a DB.