# Flutter Dart converting string to Color

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string as

```
String stringColor = "Color(0xff000000)";
```

What I want is to convert stringColor variable to actual Color.
Note:- This is merely an example I also want to convert `"TextAlign.left"` string to TextAlign.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found A working solution for `Color` part, Here is the `code`

```
String stringColor = "Color(0xff000000)";
String valueString =
    stringColor.split('(0x')[1].split(')')[0]; // kind of hacky..
print(valueString);
int value = int.parse(valueString, radix: 16);
print(value);
Color otherColor = new Color(value);
print(otherColor);
print(otherColor.runtimeType);
```

[CREDITS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835615/9577961)

You Can Also use `Extension` for the **same**, As Shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61827221/9577961)

**EDITED:**

*I have made a workaround solution by using Power of `Extension`, Its working perfectly too.*

**Add this Outside of Your Class**

```
extension AlignExtensions on String {
  toAlign() {
    if (this.contains("left")) {
      return TextAlign.left;
    } else if (this.contains("center")) {
      return TextAlign.center;
    } else if (this.contains("right")) {
      return TextAlign.right;
    } else if (this.contains("end")) {
      return TextAlign.end;
    }
  }
}
```

And to use this `Extension` *Class*, Use this line of `code`,

```
textAlign: "TextAlign.right".toAlign(),
```

Comment: Thanks so much and it really worked. Do you have any idea to do the same with `"TextAlign.left"`

Comment: @YashMakan I am also curious for the solution for that, And trying to find a perfect solution for that too.

Comment: Hey @YashMakan I have found the workaround for the textAlign  too, You Can check my updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store the color in a variable type of Color

```
Color myColor = Color(0xff123456);
```

and use this color later.

Answer (score 0):

Just use sr.replaceAll.('"', '\"') if is it String variable .Otherwish you can use Color(0xffFFFFFF)