# Flutter cant show string color code in color

Tags: flutter

I need to show the color from in my container. Mean i have color codes in string format and i need to use as the Container Color.

```
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: widget.product.colors[i].toColor(),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
```

This is the simple code i am doing like this but its showing error

```
Invalid argument(s): Can not interpret string 0xFFF6625E
```

If i remove the .toColor() then its showing

```
Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'.
```

Can any one please tell how can i show this ?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835146/how-to-convert-flutter-color-to-string-and-back-to-a-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    //make sure that the widget.product.colors[i] is a hex code (i.e: "0xff0000")
     color : Color(int.parse(widget.product.colors[i])),
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
     border: Border.all(color: Color(int.parse(kPrimaryColor)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a method like this..

```
static Color hexToColor(String code) {
    if(code.length == 6) {
      return Color(int.parse(code.substring(0, 6), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
    }
    else {
      return Color(int.parse(code.substring(0, 8), radix: 16) + 0x00000000);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Supercharged](https://pub.dev/packages/supercharged) package:

```dart
"#ff00ff".toColor(); // painless hex to color
"red".toColor(); // supports all web color names
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
color: const Color(widget.product.colors[i]),
```