# How to change text color based on user id in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to specify a color on the user's name just like Whatsapp's group chat where each user has different name color:

[image]

But I don't seem to know how to implement it.

Here is my bubble's code:

```
Container(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            overflow: Overflow.visible,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12,vertical: 12,),
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 2),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.70),
                      child:
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: // This is the color I want to specify on each users
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),),
                          SizedBox(height: 5,),
                          Text(
                            message,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5,),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left:0,
                top: 2,
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: TriangleClipper(),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 30,
                    color: showTriangle?Color(0xFFEEEEEE):Colors.transparent,
                  ...
```

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this. Just use a condition to show various color based on user id.

```
Text(name,
     style: TextStyle(
            color: (user_id == 1)? Colors.red : (user_id) == 2 ?Colors.blue : Colors.black, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
       ),),
```

Comment: what if the users inside a group chat is more then 10, is it possible to random a color and specify it to each users?

Comment: @Fahmida it is not useful when we have more users

Answer (score 1):

Instead writing conditions for every user. You can use generate colors randomly.

Follow any of the approach below:

- `Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0)`

  - import math as `import 'dart:math' as math;`
- `Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)]`
- 

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

final rnd = math.Random();

Color getRandomColor() => Color(rnd.nextInt(0xffffffff));
```

Comment: I've tried this and it works, but whenever I exit the group chat and open it again, the color changes

Comment: in your response data add a key like color...and generate random color only once

Comment: @nagendranag it would be very helpful if you could provide a simple example for adding a key that would generate random color only once and that text to have a persistent color of what it had from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to get data for the chat, you will probably have FutureBuilder

```
 var backgroundColor = Colors.red;
    
    FutureBuilder(
    future: http.get('http://google.com')
    builder:(context,snapshot){
    backgroundColor =  snapshot.data[index].color
    
    return AwesomeData(snapshot.data)
    }
    ),
```

Only yes, one problem remains, how will you store the color in the database in a row?
Then the snapshot.data[index].color variable will contain a string with the desired color,
then it will need to be converted to color
[How to convert Flutter color to string and back to a color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835146/how-to-convert-flutter-color-to-string-and-back-to-a-color)

Comment: If you have several users 2 or more, just a number in If there will be more and return the desired color

if (snapshot.data[index].color == 2 ) {
                                  backgroundColor = Colors.white;
if (snapshot.data[index].color == 3 ) {
                                  backgroundColor = Colors.white;

Comment: what if we have 100 users. do we need to write 100 conditions?

Comment: No, if 100 or more, then simply set the color of the variable depending on the color in the database
backgroundColor = snapshot.data[index].color

Comment: didn't get it can you please update it in your answer